# How to Change a Column Formula that Sums

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a workbook with 13 sheets, one Overview and 12 more each one month.  It is used to register time. On each sheet there is the Pause column.

Depending on where I click I see:

```
=WENN((G9 > 6);0,75;WENN((G9 > 3);0,5;0))
```

or

```
=WENN((G17 > 6);0,75;WENN((G17 > 3);0,5;0))
```

I think if my version of Excel was in English it would say:

```
=IF((G9 > 6);0,75;IF((G9 > 3);0,5;0))
=IF((G17 > 6);0,75;IF((G17 > 3);0,5;0))
```

and this is in all 12 Sheets.

I would like to modify the `0,75` value above to `0,5` without manually going through every row.

How might I do this?

The Sheet was made with Excel 2007, but I am currently using MSFT Off Prof Plus 2010 (Excel is part of the package).

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one-off change? or do you want the value to be customizable?

If it is a one-off, you can just use the search and replace function of excel.

eg: replace ";0,75;" with ";0,5;"

if you want to be able to change it more often then you just need to take the numbers out of your equation and replace them with a reference to a cell containing your value.